# How can I fix eslint definition for rule 'sap-....' was not found?

Tags: sapui5, webstorm, eslint

I'm using SAP eslint configuration and have all the config files and still I get this errors:

[image]

Any suggestions?

PS: I'm using WebStorm

Config:

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true
  },
  "globals": {
    "sap": true,
    "jQuery": true
  },
  "rules": {
    "sap-no-localhost": 2,
    "sap-no-ui5base-prop": 2,
    "sap-usage-basemastercontroller": 2,
    "sap-no-dom-access": 2,
    "sap-no-global-selection": 2,
    "sap-timeout-usage": 2,
    "sap-no-history-manipulation": 2,
    "sap-no-ui5-prop-warning": 2,
    "sap-no-proprietary-browser-api": 2,
    "no-use-before-define": 2,
    "no-redeclare": 2,
    "no-extra-boolean-cast": 2,
    "no-shadow": 2,
    "no-reserved-keys": 2,
    "no-unused-vars": [2, {"vars": "all", "args": "none"}],
    "no-extend-native": 2,
    "no-eq-null": 2,
    "eqeqeq": 2,

    "no-underscore-dangle": 0,
    "new-cap": 0,
    "quotes": 0,
    "camelcase": 0,
    "eol-last": 0
  }
}
```

Comment: ESLint doesn't have this rules built-in (http://eslint.org/docs/rules/), that's why it can't find them. You should probably install some additional ESLint plugin that adds these rules, if it's available.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the configuration that you provided, SAP rules are using outdated `custom-rules` approach instead of a plugin. You have to download all of the SAP rules, put them in the directory and configure WebStorm to run ESLint with [--rulesdir](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface#rulesdir) switch.